# How to send a html POST request with no body?

Tags: java, html

I'm trying to control my Roku from a java application.  You do this by sending a html POST request with no body to your Roku's ip (http://192.000.1.82:8060/keydown/Left).  Currently I have this code:

```
HttpURLConnection urlConn;
URL mUrl = new URL("html://192.000.1.82:8060/keypress/Right");
urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) mUrl.openConnection();
urlConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
```

However, nothing seems to be happening.  The [SDK](https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/External+Control+Guide) says "keydown is followed by a slash and the name of the key pressed. Keydown is equivalent to pressing down the remote key whose value is the argument passed. This command is sent via a POST with no body."  Maybe I'm misinterpreting this?

What am I doing wrong?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did'nt get you actually . would you please post any error log

Comment: There isn't one, the program runs through.  However, it does not trigger on my Roku and surely that code is a POST request with no body seen as it has no body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is already answered . Please check the following link

[[Java - sending HTTP parameters via POST method easily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205980/java-sending-http-parameters-via-post-method-easily][1])